# Why is it possible to use partial fraction decomposition in this way?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, polynomials, partial-fractions

Consider the function $ f(z)=\frac{z}{1-z-z^2}$, I'm trying to determine the power series for the function by using partial fraction decomposition. I tried to expand it into $$f(z)=
\frac{A}{(z-\alpha)}+\frac{B}{(z-\beta)}=\frac{1}{\alpha-\beta}\left( \frac{\alpha}{(z-\alpha)}-\frac{\beta}{(z-\beta)} \right)=\frac{1}{\alpha-\beta} \left( \frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{\beta}}-\frac{1}{1-z / \alpha}\right)
$$
And then use the geometric series from there. But this doesn't quite give the desired results (Or at least it's not obvious that it's equivalent).

Instead, I looked up other solutions, where they expanded $f(z)=\frac{A}{1-z\alpha} + \frac{B}{1-z\beta}$
But I have never seen this kind of expansion before. Where does this come from? why is $1-z-z^2=(1-z\alpha)(1-z\beta)$? And can we factor all polynomials in such way (Because that is completely new to me)?

$\alpha,\beta$ are roots of the denominator of $f(z)$.

Comment: Before partial fractions you should learn algebraic factorization.

Comment: Because of the formula for geometric series has $1-\square$ in the denominator, everything runs smoother if you factor the denominator as $(1-\alpha z)(1-\beta z)$ instead of the usual way.

Comment: @ZAhmed Can you elaborate? I have only learned that a polynomial can be factorized into all of its roots of the form $(z-r_1)(z-r_2)(z-r_3)...$, I have never seen before that it's possible to factorize polynomials as $(1-zr_1)(1-zr_2)(1-zr_3)...$

Comment: Notice that $az^2+bz+c=a(z-z_1)(z-z_2)=(az_1z_2)(1-\frac{1}{z_1}z)(1-\frac{1}{z_2}z)$ where $a z_1 z_2, 1/z_1, 1/z_2$ are just constants.

Comment: You can convert between the two types. For instance, if $f(z)=(z-r_1)(z-r_1)\cdots(z-r_n)$ then you can multiply and divide by $r_i$s to get $f(z)=a(1-r_1^{-1}z)(1-r_2^{-1}z)\cdots(1-r_n^{-1}z)$ with $a=(-1)^n r_1\cdots r_n$.

Comment: You say that the result is not obviously equivalent - I suspect that it is, if you use the fact that $\alpha\beta=-1$. So don't worry, you haven't made a mistake, it's just that the other factorisation is often easier to work with.

Comment: @runway44, Okay thanks that make sense. I think the issue was that I didn't realise that the two roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$ was related in the way $1/\alpha=-\beta$ and similarly for the other root.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I somehow get the wrong sign, could you perhaps take a look and see where it goes wrong? If I use the geometric series on the expression in my post I get: $\frac{1}{\alpha-\beta}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\beta^{n}}-\frac{1}{\alpha^{n}}\right) z^{n}\right)$. Using your relation I can get the roots into the numerator: $\frac{1}{\alpha-\beta}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left((-\alpha)^{n}-(-\beta)^{n}\right)\right) z^{n}$ , but I want to get the opposite sign of this expression.

Comment: If $\alpha,\beta$ are roots of $z^2+z-1$ then I find that $A,B$ are the negatives of what you write at line 3.

Comment: @ancientmathematician So do you get that $A=-\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-\beta}$ and $B=\frac{\beta}{\alpha-\beta}$? I don't quite see how I can get that.

If I have $\frac{z}{(z-\alpha)(z-beta)}=\frac{A}{(z-\alpha)}+\frac{B}{(z-\beta)}$ if I multiply by the denominator I get: $z=A(z-\beta)+B(z-\alpha)$, which I believe gets me $B=-\frac{\beta}{\alpha-\beta}$ and $A=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-\beta}$

Comment: @Tom the LHS is not $\frac{z}{(z-\alpha)(z-\beta)}$ it is $-\frac{z}{(z-\alpha)(z-\beta)}$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, Oh i'm sorry. I mean $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of $1-z-z^2$. But that's weird. They both have the same roots?  So both polynomials gets factored in the same way?

Comment: Oh never mind, I forgot about the coefficient in the factorization, which is probably -1 in this case. That makes much more sense now.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thank you very much for your help!